# How to implement Linkedin login in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, linkedin-api, manifest.json

I am a new to chrome extension.I want to **implement Linkedin login to get user basic** info such as name from **chrome extension**.I am not getting how to implement this:

I have done the following steps:

1) Created App in Linkedin to get app id

2) In index.html I have included the following script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">

        api_key:<app-id>
        authorize:true
        onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
        scope: r_basicprofile r_emailaddress

  </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">

       function onLinkedInLoad(){
            IN.Event.on(IN,"auth",getProfileData);
       }


       function getProfileData() {
       IN.API.Profile("me").fields("id", "first-name", "last-name", 
       "headline", 
       "location", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", "email- 
       address").result(displayProfileData).error(onError);
      }
      function displayProfileData(data){
      var user = data.values[0];
      console.log(user);
      }
      function onError(error) {
         console.log(error);
      }
      </script>
```

3) In body of index.html added button:

```
    <button onclick="onLinkedInLoad()">Linkedin</button>
```

4) In manifest.json added this:

```
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'  platform.linkedin.com; 
    object-src 'self'",
```

I am getting the following **error** when loading extension:

```
    Ignored insecure CSP value "platform.linkedin.com" in directive 'script- 
    src'.
```

When I remove this and clicks button,nothing happens. What I am doing wrong?How to get rid of this?

Comment: I believe you need to add https:// before platform.linkedin.com

Comment: I have done http and https both but nothing works:/

Comment: It gives this error Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spark-md5/3.0.0/spark-md5.min.js https://connect.facebook.net https://platform.linkedin.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: Worst case scenario, go for script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;  test it, remove step by step and see what is the issue

Comment: Done the implementation using oauth process in Angular JS.Thanks

Comment: I have now a similar situation using magic.link framework to login with linkedin from a chrome extension (v3) and When i click on sign in it doesnt do anything, I realised that If I run the popup from a standalone tab it works well and initiate the redirection to the linkedin page, not sure what im missing. (No errors)